# bash script to reload browser if closes with error

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi2

I'm running a Raspberry Pi 2 on a screen to display a website. The Epiphany browser will sometimes close unexpectedly.

I'm trying to make a script that will reload the browser if it fails, the problem I'm having is there are xdotool commands that run afterwards that I cannot figure out where to place.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

until epiphany "http://localhost/index.php" ; do
echo "Service 'epiphany' crashed with exit code #?. Respawning..." >&2
sleep 1
done
```

This script runs, opens the browser, and will reload the browser if the process is killed. I need the following to run after it's started:

```
sleep 10
xdotool search --class epiphany windowactivate
xdotool key F11
```

This makes epiphany go full screen

```
while ps ax | grep -v grep |epiphany ; do
sleep 60
echo "Refreshing page"
xdotool search --class epiphany windowactivate
xdotool key F5
done
```

This refreshes the screen after a minute, and repeats every 60.

The reason why I don't have the web page itself refresh, is if there is a disruption in the network, it will blank out the screen with a Page not found and not retry again.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with in the end:

screen.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -a /home/pi/.config/epiphany/session_state.xml ];
     then
     rm /home/pi/.config/epiphany/session_state.xml;
fi

epiphany "http://localhost/index.php" &
sleep 10
xdotool search --desktop 0 --class epiphany-browser windowactivate
xdotool key F11

while ps ax |grep -v grep| grep epiphany; do
sleep 30
xdotool search --desktop 0 --class epiphany-browser windowactivate
xdotool key F5
done
```

web.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/pi/screen.sh &
wait
until /home/pi/screen.sh; do
echo "Epiphany has closed in error, respawning..."
sleep 1
done
```

If you terminate the pid of epiphany, it will restart the browser on the next refresh cycle (30 seconds).

If you close the browser, it will exit the process.

Comment: you can accept your own answer after 48(?) hrs to gain valuable reputation points. Good Q and As, keep posting!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably combine them into a single script.
This would be the combined file:

combined.sh:

```
#/bin/bash

epiphany "http://localhost/index.php" &
sleep 10
xdotool search --class epiphany windowactivate
xdotool key F11

while ps ax | grep -v grep |epiphany ; do
sleep 60
echo "Refreshing page"
xdotool search --class epiphany windowactivate
xdotool key F5
done
```

service.sh

```
#/bin/bash

until combined.sh ; do
echo "Service 'epiphany' crashed with exit code #?. Respawning..." >&2
sleep 1
done
```

I am doing this off the top of my head and don't have a raspberry to test, but it should work.  The first script doesn't stop until epiphany closes, and when it closes the combined.sh executes again.

Comment: I had to mod service.sh to read until ~/combined.sh, otherwise it was saying command not found. The combined.sh runs fine on its own, but when run through the service.sh, when epiphany terminates badly the combined.sh closes, and nothing else happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Ephiphany maximized (not fullscreen) without other tools and restart if it crashes:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script that runs Ephipany browser and restarts it if it crashes.

WEBPAGEDIR=/home/pi/bin/WebPage
LOGFILE="$WEBPAGEDIR/WebPage_$(date '+%Y%m').log"

function log {
    LogStr="[$(date '+%F %X')] $1"
    echo "$LogStr"
    echo "$LogStr" >> "$LOGFILE"
}

function rmfile {
    rm "$WEBPAGEDIR/$1" &>/dev/null
}

function runBrowser {
    log "Starting browser"

    #-- delete old Epiphany session files so browser starts maximized
    rmfile states.xml
    rmfile session_state.xml~
    rmfile session_state.xml
    rmfile bookmarks.rdf
    rmfile cookies.sqlite
    rmfile ephy-*

    epiphany -a --profile="$WEBPAGEDIR" "$WEBPAGEDIR/index.html" &> /dev/null

    return $?
}

log "----------------"
log "New Session"


#-- start browser.  Restart it if it crashes --------- 
until runBrowser; do
    log "Browser crashed with exit code $?.  Restarting browser ..."
    sleep 1
done

# --- exit -----------------
log "Ended Session"
exit 0
```